# How to set Default @From Parameter to show Last three hours record in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using an SSRS Report to check the reports, and I want to set Default @From Value always should be last three hours records and @To values should be Execution.

now I am using a separate Dataset to retrieve last three hours record sometimes it is not working properly, sometimes it shows one-hour records by default and sometimes 2 hours report

```
DECLARE @From smalldatetime 
DECLARE @To smalldatetime
SET @From = DATEADD(HOUR, - 3, GETDATE())
SET @To = GETDATE()
SELECT * FROM MyDataBase
WHERE   (DateTime BETWEEN @From AND @To)
```

please help to set the default values @from parameter using the Built-in expression

Comment: This query works fine for one day, if i am checking the report at early morning 1 AM, it will show the data from 12 AM to 1 AM, the same way if i check the report at 4 AM, it will show the report from 1 AM to 4 AM, please help me to get this solved

Comment: The query you have should work, as long as the date values in your data always including a time. Can you edit the question to include some data in a date range where you have seen issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For @From create a Date/Time parameter with this default value:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour,-3,Now())
```

For @To create a Date/Time parameter with this default value:

```
=Now()
```

Comment: This is working fine, and can i use the [executiontime] instead of =Now() for the @To parameter